# Patterns for nested classes?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, nested

I seek an explanation for why member-classes don't work like member-functions.

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
  Base ():my_stuff ()
  {
  };

  struct Stuff
  {
    Stuff ()
    {    
        std::cout << "Base created Stuff" << std::endl;
    };
  };

  Stuff my_stuff;


};


class Derived: Base
{
public:
  struct Stuff
  {
    Stuff ()
    {
      std::cout << "Derived created Stuff" << std::endl;
    };
  };

};

int
main ()
{
  Base the_base;
  Derived the_derived;

  return (0);
}
```

Output:

> Base created Stuff
>
> Base created Stuff

vs. Desired output:

> Base created Stuff
>
> Derived created Stuff

A number of similar examples work similarly, unless I overload the constructor explictly. Let's say I want to avoid that, as in my case, because I have a ton of derived classes.

I am skeptical there is a solution, otherwise perhaps the compiler would allow me to write "virtual class" as a specifier, which is actually my aim.

I acknowledge this may sound unreasonable, yet Python allows it and I recently made the switch :)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: comments have pointed out the question is not clear, so I'll give it another shot.
What is considered good practice (or a good pattern) for related classes A, B, C... that use components X, Y, Z... respectively, but in the same way?

Take iterator as an example. Each standard container implements its own iterator. My expectation is therefore that a common container ancestor exists, having as a member the base class for iterator. If it is so, how is it accomplished?

Thanks again

Comment: C++ is C++, it is not Python or Javascript or Java or C#. Don't assume or expect anything to work the same way in C++ as it does in another language and vice-versa.

Comment: Remember that inheritance is an *one-way* relationship. `Derived` is-a `Base`, but `Base` is not a `Derived`. The `Base` class *only* knows about `Base::Stuff`, there's just no way it can know anything about structures defined in derived classes.

Comment: You can't "override" either types or member variables.

Comment: IMHO, "a ton of derived classes" is the root of your problems.

Comment: what is your quesiton exactly?

Comment: Does a nested class improve: 1) readability, 2) Coding, 3) Debugging?  I don't nest classes because nested classes are more difficult to reuse.

Comment: Rather than having nested classes, consider using namespaces.

Comment: I use nested classes rarley, never to reuse them. And most questions I see about nested classes appear to be about expecting nested classes to bring some advantage they do not bring.

Comment: If one Stuff is ten bytes long, and the other one is several hundred gigabytes, you now have different instances of Base have different sizes in memory. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: also what you expect from inheritance is not inheritance. `Derived` contains a subobject of type `Base`. And `Base` has a member of type `Base::Stuff`. Just because you inherit from it, the type of its member does not magically change

Comment: As for a good use-case for a nested class: Think about a generic linked list, where only the `List` class and its interface is public. The `List` uses an internal `Node` structure for the nodes in the list, which is defined as an internal, private, and nested class. Basically, any type of class that needs internal structures for anything is a good use-case for nested classes.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual (inner) class is not possible in C++.

template might help:

```
template <typename T>
struct Stuff;

template <typename Tag>
class StuffBase
{
    Stuff<Tag> my_stuff;
public:
  StuffBase() = default;
};

class BaseTag{};
class DerivedTag{};

template <>
struct Stuff<BaseTag>
{
    Stuff() { std::cout << "Base created Stuff" << std::endl; }
};

template <>
struct Stuff<DerivedTag>
{
    Stuff() { std::cout << "Derived created Stuff" << std::endl; }
};

using Base = StuffBase<BaseTag>;
using Derived = StuffBase<DerivedTag>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TczhnjKd6)